# How to display limited data table in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I have a table called 'Goods' and there is a column called 'profit' in it. There have thousands of goods in the table but I want to make a table to show only the top 5 highest profit goods and top 5 lowest profit goods like this:

| Goods | profit |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1000 |
| B | 900 |
| C | 800 |
| D | 700 |
| E | 600 |
| Lowest Profit |  |
| V | 50 |
| W | 40 |
| X | 30 |
| Y | 20 |
| Z | 10 |

**Something I tried:**
SQL SELECT:

```php
$sql="SELECT * from goods order by profit ASC";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($query->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach($results as $row){
        $goods[]=($row->goods);
        $profit[]=($row->profit);
    }
}
```

Display table:

```
<tr>
<?php
    $col=0;
    foreach($goods as $row1=>$value){
?>
    <tr>                                                
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $goods[$col];?></th>
        <td><?php  echo $profit[$col];?></td>  
        <?php $col=$col+1 && $col<5;}?> // $col<=5 is to make the data limited to 5 but it does work            
    </tr>        
    
    <th>Lowest Profit</th>
    <?php 
        $col=0;
        foreach($goods as $row1=>$value){
    ?>
        <tr>                                                
            <th scope="row"><?php echo $goods[$col];?></th>
                <td"><?php echo $profit[$col];?></td>  </td> 
                <?php $col=$col+1 && $col<5;}?>            
            </tr>        
        </tr>
```

Comment: Use `ORDER BY profit ASC LIMIT 5` to get the 5 lowest, and `ORDER BY profit DESC LIMIT 5` to get the 5 highest.

Comment: I tried that before but how can I make the 2 ORDER BY in one SELECT statement?``` $sql= "SELECT * from goods ORDER BY profit ASC LIMIT 5 AS highest and ORDER BY profit DESC LIMIT 5 AS lowest ";``` Is this correct?

Comment: You can't do it in one statement. Do two queries: one for the first 5, the other for the last 5.

Comment: You can combine them using `UNION` into a single query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using union all.

```
SELECT * from(SELECT * from goods order by profit ASC LIMIT 5) a 
union all
SELECT * from(SELECT * from goods order by profit desc  LIMIT 5) a
```

Pls refer to below sqlfiddle. I tried on mysql. Depending on DB, this can change.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e00a4a/1

Answer (score 0):

Row_number() twice

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT *,
       row_number() over(order by profit) rn1,
       row_number() over(order by profit DESC) rn2,
   FROM goods) t
WHERE rn1 <= 5 OR rn2 <=5
```